# Can't ping github but can access github via browser at my workplace. Am I out of luck?

Tags: git, networking, proxy, http-proxy

I can access Github via the browser at my workplace, but cannot git clone because

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/user/project.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

I cannot ping github.com.  Obviously, github hasn't been whitelisted by my company.

Is there a way to piggyback on the port 80/443 that is open in Chrome?  I would need to change the console command from

```
git clone http://github.com/user/project.git
```

to something else letting me thru 80/443.  Is this possible or am I out of luck?  I can download a zip but would rather clone it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try https instead of http

Comment: I used to go with this setup: https://github.com/kornicameister/dotfiles/commit/10d5046d180fa101417bfe6b5e9720fb6c44c751 . No longer using that but maybe it will help you out.

Comment: FYI: Your browser might have been configured by IT admin to work via proxy. Browser is rather standard company tool compared to git ;-)

Comment: Yes, my Chrome browser was configured to use a proxy.  Https does not work either.  Looks like I am going to use a zip file.  Thanks for the help, amigos.